# Is it a natural greeting?

Tags: word-choice

In a chatting, a friend asked me, "What are you cooking?"
I'd like to know whether it is a natural greeting. Is it an idiom? When should it be used?

Comment: There's "What's cooking?" but it's not used much in the UK, as far as I know. If I have heard it, it would be many years ago and, yes, it is idiomatic.

Comment: What do you expect it to mean? cooking dinner or making something or ???

Comment: Is your friend a native speaker? As Mick points out, [What's cooking?](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What's+cooking%3F) is a possible greeting.

Comment: @MickSharpe This may be analogous to the conversation I had at prep with a new student who hailed from The Gambia. In an effort to demonstrate his acquaintance with idiom, he hailed me one day in the lecture hall with a hearty: "So, what happenned?"

Comment: It is not a normal greeting in American English. It could be a play on words of *What's cooking?* or it could be that someone said the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

It might mean

1. What are you making for dinner tonight?
2. What's new with you?  [But the person made a mistake, or you misheard; the phrase is "What's cooking?"]

When learning a language, it helps to be fearless in asking the person directly when you don't understand what they meant.  This gets easier with practice.